# NUnit or Fluent Assertions test for reference equality?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reference, nunit, fluent-assertions

I'm using NUnit 2.6.2 + [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/) 2.0.1.

I want to assert that two references do NOT point to the same object instance. I can't find a *clean* way to express that.

**NUnit** has `Assert.ReferenceEquals(ref1, ref2)` - but I can't find the *negated* assertion.

In **Fluent Assertions** I can't find anything to directly support this scenario.

The only way I could do it was like this:

NUnit: `Assert.False(object.ReferenceEquals(ref1, ref2));`

Fluent: `object.ReferenceEquals(ref1, ref2).Should().BeFalse();`

Both of these seem less than ideal in terms of minimal noise. Is there a better way?

Comment: NUnit does not have Assert.ReferenceEquals(ref1, ref2). All objects have a static method ReferenceEquals, in the case of Assert it has been [overloaded to fail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/nunit.framework.assert.referenceequals?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to discourage people from using it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use NotBeSameAs() method:

```
ref1.Should().NotBeSameAs(ref2);
```

Its documentation says:

> Asserts that an object reference refers to a different object than
>   another object reference refers to.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! It wasn't intuitively clear to me what `[Not]BeSameAs()` did, and I failed to read the description. Thanks!

Comment: That's the big difference between (Not)BeSameAs() and (Not)Be. The former uses reference equality, the latter object.Equals().

Answer (score 5):

You can use Is.Not.SameAs() with Nunit 3.x [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SameAsConstraint)

```
var x = new object();
Assert.That(x, Is.SameAs(x)); // success
Assert.That(x, Is.Not.SameAs(x)); // fail

var y = new object();
Assert.That(x, Is.SameAs(y)); // fail
Assert.That(x, Is.Not.SameAs(y)); // success
```